# Prestashop Upload Images to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, prestashop

I have a requirement from my client to make the prestashop (products images, categories images etc) directly upload to Google Drive. Before to start the implementation I have been looking for some tutorials but I didn't found anything. That made me think it's not so easy to implement this feature.

Do you know if is this possible without changing half of Prestashop's core?

Comment: Definitely no, you can achieve this by a module.

Comment: Definitely no because is too much work to do? Or why? I am asking because I need some reasons in order to make my client understand the situation. Thank you

Comment: Its possible, changing the core or by module, of course that changing the core IS NOT recommended because you will kill the upgrades. Both ways are too much work.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy img folder to google drive public folder and use PrestaShop media server. but google drive is not suitable choice for this usage.

Comment: It's better to use cookieless domain for static contents